# I am using following code is there any way to optimize when it comes to larger data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am using following snippet for establishing parent child relation in my data.

This works fine up to 10,000 to 20,000 rows but after let's say 100K rows it is giving out of memory errors. means space complexity and time complexity is worse in both the cases how to optimize this code anyone have any idea?

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

# Employee DF
schema = 'EMPLOYEE_NUMBER int, MANAGER_EMPLOYEE_NUMBER int'
employees = spark.createDataFrame(
[[801,None], 
[1016,801], 
[1003,801], 
[1019,801], 
[1010,1003], 
[1004,1003], 
[1001,1003],
[1012,1004], 
[1002,1004], 
[1015,1004], 
[1008,1019], 
[1006,1019], 
[1014,1019],
[1011,1019]], schema=schema)

# initial DataFrame
empDF = employees \
  .withColumnRenamed('EMPLOYEE_NUMBER', 'level_0') \
  .withColumnRenamed('MANAGER_EMPLOYEE_NUMBER', 'level_1')

i = 1

# Loop Through if you dont know recusrsive depth
while True:
  this_level = 'level_{}'.format(i)
  next_level = 'level_{}'.format(i+1)
  this_level_dept = 'level_{}'.format(i) #some more columns additionally
  next_leve_dept = 'level){}'.format(i+1)
  emp_level = employees \
    .withColumnRenamed('EMPLOYEE_NUMBER', this_level) \
    .withColumnRenamed('MANAGER_EMPLOYEE_NUMBER', next_level)
    .withColumnRenamed('MANAGER_dept', next_level_dept)
    .withColumnRenamed('emp_dept', this_level_dept )
  empDF = empDF.join(emp_level, on=this_level, how='left')
  
  # Check if DF is empty. Break loop if empty, Otherwise continue with next level
  if empDF.where(col(next_level).isNotNull()).count() == 0:
    break
  else:
    i += 1

# Sort columns and show
empDF.sort('level_0').select('level_0').show()#we can avoid this
```

Thanks for help

Comment: can you get rid of sort?

Comment: I am not using sort in my actual code @chen

Comment: can you explain and describe more about how you want to achieve?

Comment: Please provide input and output samples to understand the problem better. I think the join on every iteration is causing the issue.

Comment: @Jonathan I want to achieve parent child relationship based on their department let's say we need employee whose department is different